# mysql service crashes after every restart

Tags: mysql, xampp

i am having trouble with starting mysql , i have xampp 3.2.2 with  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 win10 64-bit 8gb ram , every time i start my computer and run xampp the mysql client crashes saying

> Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace
>   niche_spa/rh_captcha uses space ID: 180 at filepath:
>   .\niche_spa\rh_captcha.ibd. Cannot open tablespace
>   sms/sms_beatport_artist_subscribers which uses space ID: 180 at
>   filepath: .\sms\sms_beatport_artist_subscribers.ibd InnoDB: Error:
>   could not open single-table tablespace file
>   .\sms\sms_beatport_artist_subscribers.ibd

every time its a different `.ibd` file that it notifies , then i edit the `my.ini` file and uncomment

```
innodb_force_recovery=1
```

and then start mysql from xampp , then it starts successfully , and then i comment out

```
#innodb_force_recovery=1
```

and restart the service again, and every thing runs smoothly untill i restart my system , and then i have to repeat these steps again.

why does it happen again and again any idea

Comment: Sounds like you have two mechanisms trying to launch the MySQL server. Maybe you have installed `xampp` _and_ `MySQL`?

Comment: i do have mysql workbench installed with xampp , would that make any difference

Comment: The workbench is a client, that is not relevant here. What I referred to is a separate setup as a service which tries to launch the MySql server so that the tables are then already locked when xampp tries to start.

Comment: yeah i understand that, and there is no other service that would launch mysql server.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, have you found any solution? @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: @Ping have you installed `SQL SERVER` too on your system .

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, XAMPP.